# Traversing directory in Node (Grunt)

Tags: javascript, node.js, directory, gruntjs, traversal

Having a strange issue when building a [grunt plugin](https://github.com/streetlight/grunt-github-changes).

Basically, I'd like to use a node_module in my grunt task itself. To do this, I want to traverse a level up, then down into the node modules to call their one file specifically.

Originally, I wanted to do this:

```
../node_modules/github-changes/bin/index.js
```

However, I get the following error:

```
Warning: Command failed: /bin/sh: 1: ../node_modules/github-changes/bin/index.js: not found
Use --force to continue.
```

So, for now I have a hack on using Node's __dirname variable, but it's not very pretty:

```
var dirHack = __dirname.replace("/tasks", ""), // Terrible hack, need to fix
       ghC = dirHack + '/node_modules/github-changes/bin/index.js';
```

This works, but I'd love to avoid it.

You can see the line [here](https://github.com/streetlight/grunt-github-changes/blob/master/tasks/github_changes.js#L46).

What's missing that's causing that error? Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `github-changes` is a dependency, you can resolve a path to file within the package using `ghC = require.resolve('github-changes/bin/index.js')`.

But you're getting that error because you're trying to run that file as a shell script, which it is not. You need to run it with node. The easiest way to find the path to the node executable is `process.execPath`. See http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_execpath

Here is an example:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var ghC = require.resolve('github-changes/bin/index.js');
exec(process.execPath + ' ' + ghC, function(error) {});
```